# When I use a KRL module do I get the deployed version?

Tags: module, krl

Does importing a module get the deployed version in KRL? Suppose I want to use the development version, can I get that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will currently get the same version as the app you are running. We will be making a few small changes to this behavior to make it more clear and provide more options.

Comment: Meaning the deployed version?

Comment: I think it means that a dev app will get the dev module and a deployed app will get the deployed module. More, clear options will be good. Perhaps for now when you release a module (for public consumption) you should make a copy and use that for continuing development.